# Recycler view does not show up

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am having problem with my recyclerview I builed an app in android studio which suppose to create contacts and watch their cards using cardview and recyclerview the issue is that the list of contacts is not shown instead I am seeing a white screen
so here is my code:

```
import android.net.sip.SipSession;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
/*Connect contact list to
 *
 * */

public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {

    private List<Contact> contacts;
    public ContactAdapter(List<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    interface ContactsListener{
        void onContactClicked(int position,View view);
    }
    ContactsListener listener;

public void setListener(ContactsListener listener){

    this.listener=listener;
}




    public class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView contactpicture;
        TextView contactname;
        TextView contactphone;
        TextView contactemail;



        public ContactViewHolder(View itemview) {

            super(itemview);
            contactpicture = itemview.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
            contactphone = itemview.findViewById(R.id.contact_email);

            contactphone = itemview.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone);
            contactname = itemview.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (listener != null)
                        listener.onContactClicked(getAdapterPosition(), view);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override

    public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType){
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_layout,parent,false);
            ContactViewHolder holder=new ContactViewHolder(view);
            return holder;

        }
    @Override

    public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder holder,int position){
        Contact contact=contacts.get(position);
        holder.contactpicture.setImageBitmap(contact.getPhoto());
        holder.contactname.setText(contact.getName());
        holder.contactphone.setText(contact.getPhone());
        holder.contactemail.setText(contact.getEmail());

        }
    @Override

    public int getItemCount(){

            return contacts.size();
        }
    }
```

```
package com.example.b_safe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

/*Define the list of contacts*/
public class ContactsList extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle saveInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_contacts_activity);//לבדוק שזה מתקיים
        RecyclerView recyclerview=findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
        recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager( this));//צריך להוסיף this
        ContactManager manager=ContactManager.getInstance(this);
        ContactAdapter adapter=new ContactAdapter(manager.getContacts());
        recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setListener(new ContactAdapter.ContactsListener() {
            @Override
            public void onContactClicked(int position, View view) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

```
package com.example.b_safe;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
/*Adds new member to the contacts list
 *
 *
 * */
public class AddContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    EditText nameEt,phone_numberEt,emailEt;
    ImageView img;
    final int CAMERA_REQUEST=1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_contact_activity);
        nameEt=findViewById(R.id.name_input);
        phone_numberEt=findViewById(R.id.phone_input);
        emailEt=findViewById(R.id.email_input);
        img=findViewById(R.id.photo_result);
        Button takepicture=findViewById(R.id.take_pic);
        takepicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//Activation
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent camera=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(camera,CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){ //checks if results where properly
            bitmap=(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);//saving as contact's photo
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {//Load menu type
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {//fulfill actions

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_save:
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Please confirm")
                        .setMessage("Would you like to save the following contact?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                Contact contact=new Contact(nameEt.getText().toString(),phone_numberEt.getText().toString(),emailEt.getText().toString(),bitmap);
                                ContactManager manager=ContactManager.getInstance(AddContactActivity.this);
                                manager.addContact(contact);//Manager saved data

                                //Data zeroing
                                nameEt.setText("");
                                phone_numberEt.setText("");
                                emailEt.setText("");
                                img.setImageBitmap(null);

                            }})
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(AddContactActivity.this,"The conatct saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(AddContactActivity.this,"The conatct saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }).show();
                break;
            case R.id.action_back:
                finish();

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);//Loads activity
    }
}
```

AdapterActivity is the subclass adapter AddContactActivity creates new contacts and the problem is with the ContactsList activity which holds the list and does not show up